# How to deny create function to user on PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

How does one go about explicitly denying the create function ability of a non superuser in postgres? I looked into the documentation, but was unable to find anything of value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-grant.html) for the documentation. You would use the Revoke command in place of grant and just specify Create.

```
REVOKE { { CREATE | TEMPORARY | TEMP } [,...] | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
ON DATABASE dbname [, ...]
TO { username | GROUP groupname | PUBLIC } [, ...]
```

EDIT:

[Here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-revoke.html) is where you go for Revoke, which has more options.

```
REVOKE [ GRANT OPTION FOR ]
{ EXECUTE | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
ON FUNCTION funcname ( [ [ argmode ] [ argname ] argtype [, ...] ] ) [, ...]
FROM { username | GROUP groupname | PUBLIC } [, ...]
[ CASCADE | RESTRICT ]
```

Comment: That would be helpful except I need REVOKE CREATE on FUNCTION.  Based on the documentation that is not an option

Comment: sorry, I misread. Please see edit.

Comment: ahh there we go, not enough rep to upvote you sorry